# Can I access the additional detection in UITextView that is not available in NSDataDetector?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsdatadetector

I know the "correct" way to detect text in a string is to use NSDataDetector, but a UITextView can detect more types of data, for example shipment tracking numbers and physical units.

Is there a way to perform the same detection in Swift either by having UITextView give me the things it has detected or ideally by using whatever improved detection is going on under the hood directly?